# Configure Avatar button not found in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, avatar

Hi every body today I installed Unity 5.6.1f1 and I noticed that the Configure Avatar button on the right inspector not found why?

[image]

**Edit**

when I selected the model not the avatar, the Configure button still not appear in my project it looks like this 
 [the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PN01.png)

but it should looks like this as Unity website!

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it wrong. [This](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConfiguringtheAvatar.html) is how you configure your avatars.
To correctly configure your avatar, first you need to select your model (not the avatar), and in the Rig tab in the inspector, set its `Animation Type` as `Humanoid`.

Comment: they sayed that "need to go into the Configure Avatar mode to ensure your Avatar is valid and properly set up" but where is the configure avatar mode ??

Comment: Select the model, not the avatar

Comment: I select the model not the avatar and read the link that you put , the view that contains Model, Rig, Animation appeared like in the link but under the Avaatar defenition should be the Configure button but not found why?, I'll edit my post and add the image

Comment: To edit the avatar, you need to select humanoid as your type.

Comment: thanks for you, the button appeared finally because you should select the Animation type to Humanoid not Generic

Comment: I will edit the answer and you can accept is as correct.